# Viewing ArcGIS Generated Tiles in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, tiles

I have created Cache imagery using the [Manage Tile Cache](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/manage-tile-cache.htm) tool of ArcGIS Desktop. This tool creates cache imagery from the data provided. After creating this cache, i can open that in ArcMap easily from ArcCatalog, just like a raster imagery.

How can I open that cache created dataset in QGIS?

I want to open that Cache dataset in QGIS, and view it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, in the default state that ESRI generates cache (bundles etc) you can't bring that into QGIS without some sort of converter and it just doesn't exist.

There are a couple of options that come to mind,

1. view the raw images in QGIS.
2. using ArcGIS server, you could publish a map service, and then point to the cache and make a connection to that map service in QGIS.

Comment: Thanks, But i will keep this question open, so that if there will be an answer to the question.